# Hibernate foreign key column length mismatch

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have a Hibernate Entity, say A, with a column defined as

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
private String name;
```

This A entity is being referenced as foreign key in another entity B as

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_a_b", value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT), name = "aName",
        referencedColumnName = "name", updatable = false)
@NotNull
private A a;
```

Now when hibernates try to create table, it is creating column `name` as varchar(50) in table A, whereas column `aName` in table B is being created as Varchar(255). This is causing the following error while creating foreign key constraint in MSSQL:

```
2018-05-10 07:34:42 ERROR SchemaUpdate:main - Column 'A.name' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'B.aName' in foreign key 'fk_a_b'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
```

I do not see an option to set column length for column `aName` which is being used to reference column `name`. The only solution I see is using `columnDefinition` which I dont want to use as it get specific to a database. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem. I'm not using MSSQL, but it seems to happen with the databases I've tested too, which are H2 and MySQL, although an error is not thrown there.

Specifying `@Column(length = ...)` on the referenced column explicitly solves the problem. This should work:

```java
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 2, max = 50)
@Column(length = 50)
private String name;
```